# Counting Subgrids satisfying specific conditions

Tags: arrays, algorithm

So I came upon an interesting algorithms problem and I'm trying to think of the most efficient solution. So there is a 2d array, and each square in the array is either red, white, or blue. We want to count the number of subrectangles of the array which contain at least one red square, no blue squares, and white squares don't matter. What is the best way to go about this?
It seems like a simple problem statement. Clearly we can iterate through all possible subgrids and test if they work, but this is very inefficient. Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to avoid duplicates; for example, you can identify a rectangle using `x0,y0,x1,y1`.

```
open, valid = empty sets of rectangles
add all red squares to a set `open`
while not `open` empty,
    take the first `open` rectangle
    for each direction, 
       try to grow it 1 square in that direction
          if growth possible (not outside matrix, not blue), 
              and result not in `valid` or `open`, 
                  add to `open`
    add it to `valid`
```

The size of `valid` is the count you seek. Could probably be more optimal, but at least it seems correct, and should be substantially faster than looking at all possible rectangles because it a) never looks a rectangles without a red, and b) never keeps looking once a rectangle would involve a blue.

A "look at all possible rectangles" algorithm on a size-n grid would have to look at `~n^4` rectangles (back-of-the envelope, as there are `n^2` `x0,y0` pairs & `n^2` `x1,y1` pairs); and, for each rectangle, check that there is a blue and a red (so, `O(n^5)` is a low-ball estimate; `O(n^6)` may be closer to the mark). Importantly, it will have that cost regardless of distribution of red & blue. My proposal has better complexity if there are less valid results: `O(n^2)` if there are no reds, or if they are all surrounded by blues (checkerboard pattern). It is also of lower complexity in the worst case, as it only grows when valid -- probably around `O(n^4)` worst-case, defined as all-red map.

Comment: Wow thanks, I didn't think about it from this perspective. It seems very similar to floodfill in my opinion. If the array is N x N, what is the time complexity of your algorithm?